# install php modules in server 16.04

Tags: server, 16.04, apache2, php

I have installed the server with the intention of running owncloud, it is all ready to go but when I get to the setup page in a browser owncloud presents me with a list of php modules that are not installed are there does not seem to be any info on how to add them.
If anyone can advise me I would be most pleased, thanks, everything else is running fine, set up certificates and everything
Missing modules zip, dom, XMLWriter, XMLReader, libxml, mb multibyte, GD, SimpleXML, cURL

Comment: Update the apt db with `sudo apt-get update` in the terminal then run the following `sudo apt-cache search php7.0` and this should list all the available php7 modules. Then you can install what you need from that list  with `sudo apt-get install desired_package_name_here`. Note that since you haven't specified the PHP version you're using I assume it's 7.0 which comes by default with 16.04.

Comment: Thanks for that info Sledge Hammer I finally worked it out for myself by reading more of the gz readmes that are in /usr/share  and it is running really beautifully now. Now all I need is a few days to explore all the things it does

Comment: @SledgeHammer post this as an answer? It's useful.